# How to select rows that have certain values present in another column

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table :

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 1 | B |
| 1 | C |
| 2 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 3 | A |

my goal is to have the table where I have only IDs that have A,B,C present per id,

in this case it is:

| id |
| --- |
| 1 |

how to construct the SQL query for that ?

Comment: Could you please tag your DBMS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One canonical approach uses aggregation:

```sql
SELECT id
FROM yourTable
WHERE value IN ('A', 'B', 'C')
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT value) = 3;
```

Comment: Duplicate removal is needed before ```group by id```.

Comment: I disagree with your interpretation of the question.

Answer (score 0):

To use `exists` statement like this:

```sql
select id from ${table} a where value = 'A' 
and exists (select 1 from ${table} b where a.id = b.id and b.value = 'B')
and exists (select 1 from ${table} c where a.id = c.id and b.value = 'C')
```

To create index on column `id` will be more nice.